# If $A = \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$ and $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A/(1 + i\sqrt{3})$, what are the $Im(f)$ and $Ker(f)$?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, ideals

> Suppose you have $A = \mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{3}] = \{ a+ib\sqrt{3}| a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. We put $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A/(1+ i\sqrt{3})$ such that for an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f$ maps $m$ to is equivalence class in $A$. Determine the $\text{Im}(f)$ and $\text{Ker}(f)$

I struggle to answer this questions, as first of all, I am rather unsure what equivalence relation should I use. I think that two elements are equivalent if their remainders when dividing by $(1 + i \sqrt{3})$ are equal. So I figured that $\text{Im}{f}$ will be equal to the set of all possible remainders of the divisions of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $(1 + i \sqrt{3})$. And here I lack any insight, as it seems to me that the remainders could equal to just about anything.

As for $\text{Ker}(f)$, I think getting to know $\text{Im}(f)$ would give me a good idea of what $\text{Ker}(f)$ would be equal to.

Comment: $a,b$ are equivalents if $a-b\in\langle 1+i\sqrt{3}\rangle$.

Comment: @Gödel So here $a$ and $b$ are equivalents if $a-b = (1 + i \sqrt{3})P$ with some $P \in A$?

Comment: Yes, they must be in the ideal generate by $1+i\sqrt{3}$